# Propagate click from tooltip to point

Tags: highcharts

How do I re-enable click on a point that have a tooltip above that point?

In previous version 2.3.2 click on a tooltip that is above that point, the event propagates to the point and the event is fired. How do I get that in version 3.0.4?

```
Demo version 3.0.4: http://jsfiddle.net/WSPaV/

Demo version 2.3.2: http://jsfiddle.net/WSPaV/13/
```

Comment: I opened your examples and in both examples click event open dialog, so what is wrong?

Comment: try move the mouse over a point so that the tooltip show up. then with the tooltip over a point click on that tooltip you will see that in version 2.3.2 the event is propagated to the point and in version 3.0.4 the event is not propagated. If you want I can do a print screen to help

Answer (score 0):

It is related with this topic https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1413 so I added comment about your situation.